# Using Recursion to Create a Countdown in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

how to define a function called countdown with one parameter (n). The function should use recursion to return an array containing the integers n through 1 based on the n parameter. If the function is called with a number less than 1, the function should return an empty array. For example, calling this function with n = 5 should return the array [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. Your function must use recursion by calling itself and must not use loops of any kind.

Comment: Can you show the code you have done so far? it will be better..

Comment: While homework questions are allowed on SO, please clearly identify it as such.

Comment: Thanks for for your concerns, I will be more careful and detailed when asking questions. This was my first time!

Answer (score 1):

```
function countdown(n) {
    return [n].concat(n > 1 ? countdown(n - 1) : []);
}
```

Comment: Very concise. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  }
  if (n === 1) {
    return [1];
  }
  return [n].concat(countdown(n-1));
}

console.log(countdown(0));
console.log(countdown(1));
console.log(countdown(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// CountUp instead of countdown: 
// Example output :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 

function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}

console.log(countup(5)) // output :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).